# Adding an alpha channel to geoTIFF image in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff, alpha, geotiff

Trying to add an alpha (transparency) channel to the RGB data in a georeferenced tiff image. I was led through the process of creating the geotiff in a separate question. The first part of the code creates a geotiff from the attached png file ([uk_dT.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmSDk.png)), the second part creates a mask from white regions, appends it to the RGB data and attempts to modify the appropriate tags before rewriting the geotiff in a new file. However the resultant image is blank. I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the 'photometric' tag but can't see the problem?

```
file = 'uk_dT.png' ; 
[path,name,ext] = fileparts(file) ;

I = imread(file) ;
I = flipud(I);

lonmin = -17; lonmax = 10; latmin = 47; latmax = 63;

% Write to geotiff
R = georasterref('RasterSize',size(I),'LatitudeLimits',[latmin,latmax],'LongitudeLimits',[lonmin,lonmax]);
tiffile = strcat(name,'.tif') ;
geotiffwrite(tiffile,I,R) ;

%% Now we have a geotiff but need transparency.

% Make alpha mask by identifying white regions
S = sum(I,3);
mask = 255*ones(size(I,1),size(I,2));
mask(S==765) = 0; % create mask
I = cat(3,I,mask); % concatenate alpha channel onto RGB data

info = geotiffinfo(tiffile); % reload RGB tiff data

% use Tiff tags to append alpha data
tiffile2 = strcat(name,'2.tif') ;
geotiffwrite(tiffile2,I,R,'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', ...
  info.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag,'TiffTags', ...
  struct('ExtraSamples',Tiff.ExtraSamples.AssociatedAlpha, ...
  'Photometric',Tiff.Photometric.Separated));
```

Edit: Having played with this problem a bit more, it appears it is impossible to add an alpha channel to a geoTIFF in Matlab (at least without some clever workaround) for a couple of reasons:

1: the 'Photometric' tag should be set to 'RGB', as the colour space we're creating is RGB+alpha.  However there is an interlock in geotiffwrite which prevents you from writing anything other than an x*y*3 array when this tag is set to RGB.  The code I utilised above (found somewhere online) gets round an error by using 'Separated' instead, but this is associated with the CMYK colour space so is surely not the right setting.

2: You set the 'ExtraSamples' tag to inform that something other than RGB data is expected.  But in other examples I've seen, you also have to set the 'SamplesPerPixel' tag to 4 to reflect this.  Geotiffwrite does not recognise this as a valid tag.  In fact, diving into the geotiffwrite code and looking at the tags which are valid, there are only a fraction of the options available compared to the tiff() command.

I would love to be proved wrong but it appears that I'm going to have to manually load hundreds of files in an external package and change white areas to transparent!

Comment: I use Photoshop to open your result, the TIF image looks fine. The second output looks darker but also is not blank. How did you open the file?

Comment: There *may* be a type conversion issue, but I doubt it. Try these changes and see if it makes a difference: `S = sum(double(I),3); mask = 255*ones(size(I,1), size(I,2), 'uint8');`

Comment: Yvon - I used ArcMap to open the images.  The first tiff output looks fine for me also.  The second tiff appears black.  Only have access to Photopaint, but that throws an error that a tag is not supported for the second tiff.  Out of interest, geotiffs produced using ArcGIS load fine in both packages and transparency appears as expected. gnovice - thanks, good idea but it doesn't fix the problem for me at least.